# Why my bootstrap navigation is not working?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I downloaded bootstrap manually from http://getbootstrap.com/ ver 4.0 but i dont know why my navigation, XS, panel classes are not working i searched xs in boostrap.min.css but its not found. what is wrong with this but sm, md, lg classes are all working fine.I dont know why some classes are working & why some classes are not working, i downloaded officially & also stylesheet paths are perfect, iam fixing from last 3 weeks is it any solution.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" Content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>


<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="fa fa-align-justify"></span>
            </button>
            <span class="navbar-brand">Diffie</span>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
<div class="container">



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="hidden-xs"><b>AAA Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</b> and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>AAA Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div style="width: auto;height: auto;background-color: gray;color: white;padding: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div style="width: auto;height: auto;background-color: gray;color: white;padding: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div style="width: auto;height: auto;background-color: gray;color: white;padding: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div style="width: auto;height: auto;background-color: gray;color: white;padding: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div style="width: auto;height: auto;background-color: gray;color: white;padding: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div style="width: auto;height: auto;background-color: gray;color: white;padding: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div style="width: auto;height: auto;background-color: gray;color: white;padding: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div style="width: auto;height: auto;background-color: gray;color: white;padding: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Btw you should google for the bootstrap grid system. Your grid isn't correct at all. As far as I remember, the grid system is based on a 12-point gridsystem. You've actually 8 times a col-6 in one row. Not sure how bootstrap handels this, may it displays correctly, but I don't think its good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap 4.0 version no longer uses -xs. Using just col-2, or whatever should give about the same result.

From the bootstrap site:

> ...we’ve dropped the -xs infix from our lowest (extra small) breakpoint. xs isn’t a responsive breakpoint quite like sm, md, lg, and xl because it doesn’t start applying styles at a min-width and up. It simply applies to everything as there’s no bounding @media query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also forgot some bookstore on the header:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```